# Android billing null purchases list

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to implement In-App purchases using `'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.0.3'` library.

the app is released in the Internal test track, and have one managed product, and a single tester (another account of mine), I managed to launch a billing flow and buy the product, but I didn't acknowledge or consume the purchase, in spite of this the `responseCode` is now always `ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED` , I thought that if the purchase is not acknowledged within 5 minutes (for testers accounts) it will be refunded. why wasn't it ?

the second question is that I'm trying to consume the product so that i can continue the implementation using my only tester account, here's the `onPurchasesUpdated` function

```
override fun onPurchasesUpdated(
   billingResult: BillingResult?, purchases: MutableList<Purchase>?) {

     val resCode=billingResult!!.responseCode
     println(resCode) // prints 7 i.e ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED
     println(purchases!!.size) // nullPointerException

  }
```

the purchases list is null, what am I doing wrong ?
please let me know if you want more details, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error(i'm using java, so code is a little different)

```
@Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> list) {
```

in my case `list` was null, so what i did was just called `queryPurchases()` to load purchases again

```
List<Purchase> list2 = billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP).getPurchasesList();
```

creation of billingClient is in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#Connect)